# Array list display in Text view

Tags: android, arraylist, textview

I want to display array list from api response in a textview I tried using for loop, but it showing one time only,I need entire list at a time. When I tried using listview but it has scrolling action,I don't need scrolling action.I want to display array list at a time .Please help me..

this is my code using listview :

```
private void prepareEmergencyAll(JSONArray emergency_all) {
   LinearLayout myLayout1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listTL);
    ListView emgcyall_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.emgcyallLV);
   // LinearLayout myLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.phonelistTL);

    for(int i=0;i<emergency_all.length();i++){
        Emergency_all emglist = new Emergency_all();
        try {
            JSONObject single = emergency_all.getJSONObject(i);
            emglist.setFullname(single.getString("fullname"));
            emglist.setPhone(single.getString("phone"));
            list.add(emglist);
       //     emgcyall_list.setAdapter(adapter1);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    adapter1=new EmgcyAdapter(ViewActivity.this,list);
    emgcyall_list.setAdapter(adapter1);

  //  adapter1 = new EmgcyAdapter(,list);








    }
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Use the `TextUtils.join()` method.

Comment: can you please give sample code..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StringBuilder` for that :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : yourArrayList) {
  builder.append(s).append(" ");
}
yourTextView.setText(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        String end ="";
        for(int i = 0;i<a.size();i++){
            end = end + "\n"+a.get(i);
        }
```

You can try this, if u can't understand `StringBuilder` :)

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for listview height dynamically change..
here is the code..

```
public class Utility {
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        // listItem.measure(0, 0);
        listItem.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
}
```

and add following to your mainactivity..

```
 listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listview);
```